# SSRS BIDS 2008 Expression for YEAR part of current system date

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, bids

Does anyone know what the expression is to take the YEAR only from the current date in SSRS BIDS 2008. I need this as I have a table grouped on multiple years and I want to FILL the current year in green and leave the rest white.

I am going to use the following expresssion (minus the current year part)

=iif(Fields!Date_year.Value="***_*__*_*_**","SeaGreen","White")

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
=iif(Fields!Date_year.Value= Year(NOW) ,"SeaGreen","White")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think he means like this...

```
Iif( Year(Fields!Date_year.Value) = Year(NOW), "SeaGreen", "White")
```

he wants the year bit dynamic.

If the Date_year bit equals the current year then show it in SeaGreen ????

Comment: Try this....

Iif(Cstr(Year(Fields!Date_year.Value))=Cstr(Year(Today())), "SeaGreen", "White")

Comment: =iif(Fields!Date_year.Value="2011","SeaGreen","White")

This works perfectly but obviously I dont want to have to change the "2011" part each year, I want it to update that with the current year, do you know what I mean?

Comment: Done it:

=iif(Fields!Date_year.Value= Year(NOW) ,"SeaGreen","White")

Comment: Try iif(Fields!Date_year.Value=Format(now,"yyyy"),"SeaGreen","White")

Answer (score 1):

If your field has a date datatype, you can use the `Year()` function, like so:

```
Iif( Year(Fields!Date_year.Value) = 2011, "SeaGreen", "White")
```

If the field has a string datatype, you can convert it to a date first, using the `DateTime.Parse()` function.

Reading material:

- [SSRS - Expression Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)
- [SSRS - Working with Data Types in Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255246.aspx)

Comment: My field has been taken from a StartDate field which was accomplished using:

YEAR(StartDate) AS Date_year. So far I only have 2010 & 2011 available

Comment: The StartDate field is in the following format in a different table:

2011-11-07 00:00:00.000

Comment: This works:

=iif(Fields!Date_year.Value= Year(NOW) ,"SeaGreen","White")